# How do I count all the characters in a string without dictionary/set/lists?

Tags: character

Write and develop a function getPartsInCode which has one string parameter: productCode. The function returns a string in this format:
if product code is AABBBGH, then the function returns 2A 3B 1G 1H.

I can't seem to find any that's similar to the output I want to get. The closest was

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")

Alphabet=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o'\
          ,'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

for i in range(0,26):
    if word.count(Alphabet[i]) > 0:
        print(word.count(Alphabet[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a dictionary that corresponds each letter to a specific integer value.

```
def get_parts_in_code(code): # Creating a function that takes one parameter: code
    
    # Creating a dictionary called 'alphabet' that stores every letter and its corresponding value
    alphabet = {
        'A': 0,
        'B': 0,
        'C': 0,
        'D': 0,
        'E': 0,
        'F': 0,
        'G': 0,
        'H': 0,
        'I': 0,
        'J': 0,
        'K': 0,
        'L': 0,
        'M': 0,
        'N': 0,
        'O': 0,
        'P': 0,
        'Q': 0,
        'R': 0,
        'S': 0,
        'T': 0,
        'U': 0,
        'V': 0,
        'W': 0,
        'X': 0,
        'Y': 0,
        'Z': 0,
        'OTHER': 0, # An 'other' category for spaces, underscores, etc (anything that isn't in the english alphabet)
    }
    code = code.upper() # Making everything upercase
    code = list(code) # Converting our code into a list
    code.sort() # Sorting it alphebetically


    for letter in code: # For every letter in our list (code)
        try:
            alphabet[letter] += 1 # It should try to increase the corresponding value by one
        except:
            alphabet['OTHER'] += 1 # If that failed, then it means that the charecter is not in our dictionary, so we instead increase the 'OTHER' value

    for letter in alphabet: # For every letter in our dictionary (alphabet)
        if alphabet[letter] > 0: # Instead of printing all the zeroes, let's only print the values greater than 0
            print(letter, alphabet[letter]) # Print the letter and the corresponding values


get_parts_in_code("hello world") #Executing the function
```

In this code, we go through each item in the code and increase the dictionary value by one. In the end, we go through each value in our dictionary 'alphabet', and if the value is greater than zero, we print it. Read the comments for a line-by-line description of the code.